# Increase performance of query using h2 jar when importing from csv

Tags: java, jdbc, h2, in-memory-database

I have multiple csv files, which I am importing as in-memory tables using the *h2-1.4.194.jar.*

I then have to run complex queries consisting of atleast 2-3 inner joins.
The query does not stop executing even after 2 hours, so I tried to look at the ways to tune the performance of the h2 database-
http://iliachemodanov.ru/en/blog-en/21-databases/42-h2-performance-en

I tried to increase the CACHE size :

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mydatabase;CACHE_SIZE=131072");
```

But the following setting did not help me.

How can the h2 database be tuned?

Is there any other jar that I can use that imports the csv files and treats them as in-memory tables, which has a faster performance?

Comment: Did you check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798896/performance-issues-using-h2-db-in-embedded-mode-with-heavy-load-of-data-in-datab)?